# Swipe Delete in UItableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

in my iPad app swipe deleting not working properly. after swipe deleting it shows the delete button on cell and this not disappearing.

[image]

Comment: You might want to add some code on how you are laying out the cell and what implementation goes into the delete method.

Answer (score 0):

To delete row from UITableView implement UITableViewDataSource method:

Swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete{
       // enter your datasource updation logic hare & delete table cell
       tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you write canEditRowAt method?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
```

and then actual code to delete in this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
  UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
       //add code here for delete action
    }
}
```